# Python Tkinter button text is not visible

Tags: python, macos, button, tkinter

I am trying to display 2 buttons, but the text on the button is not visible unless I hold down the button.

[image: This is the image of the loaded window]

[image: This is the image of the window when I hold down the button]

I can only view the text if I hold down the button.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
   def __init__(self,master):
      frame = Frame(master)
      frame.pack()

      self.mb = Button(frame,
                       text = "XYZ",
                       command = self.button_click)
      self.tb = Button(frame,
                       text="ABC",
                       command=self.button_click)
      self.mb.pack(expand = 1, fill = BOTH)
      self.tb.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
      frame.mainloop()


   def button_click(self):
      print("button was clicked")

def main():
   root = Tk()
   app = App(root)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

How can I fix this so that it works normally (the text on the buttons are displayed even when I am not clicking them)?

I am running macOS Catalina and Python 3.7.4

Comment: The code is working fine on Windows and Python 3.7.4

Comment: I'm running macOS Catalina and Python 3.7.4

Comment: Try `from tkinter import ttk ; ttk.Button(` if this behave different.

Comment: This is a known issue on OSX. As @stovfl suggested, one workaround is to use the `ttk` button instead. It doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import Button

:
:
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. But I'm not sure. You can import `ttk` and change the name of the button.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

self.mb = ttk.Button(........)

self.tb = ttk.Button(........)
```